# How to align a menu bar using css and html?

Tags: html, css

The problem is that I placed a horizontal menu bar on my site that fits the whole screen or page so when I tried resizing and making the menu bar smaller to make the size the same with the other parts on the site, everytime I zoom in and out the page, the menu bar resizes unproportionally with the other parts.

To see the problem for yourself, please check my site at http://thenativeisodrafts.tumblr.com and try zooming in and out the page.

Thank you very much!

Here's the **CSS**:

```css
#cssmenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu a {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#cssmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: rgb(35,35,35);
    border-bottom: 5px solid #cd2c23;
    border-top: 5px solid #cd2c23;
    position:absolute;
    right:241px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    color: rgb(160,160,160);
    font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 70px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    -webkit-transition: color .15s;
    -moz-transition: color .15s;
    -o-transition: color .15s;
    transition: color .15s;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
    color: rgb(250,250,250);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
    background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -90px;
    width: 180px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
    -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
    transition: all .3s .1s;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    z-index: 1000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 65px;
    visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgb(250,250,250) transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul > li {
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
    color: rgb(50,50,50);
    font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    padding: 5px 8px 7px 16px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .1s;
    -moz-transition: background-color .1s;
    -o-transition: background-color .1s;
    transition: background-color .1s;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -16px;
    left: 206px;
    padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
    background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    text-align: left;
    width: 160px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

Here's the **HTML** codes:

```
<div id='cssmenu' style="width:940.5px; margin:auto">
<ul>
   <li class='active '><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: link http://thenativeiso.tumblr.com broken

Comment: Add your code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry about the link, fixed it already and I included the html codes. Thanks!

Comment: One observation, for html attributes use double quotes instead of '

Comment: Oh what's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `#cssmenu` has `position: absolute` declared on it. Remove this and you should be golden:

```css
#cssmenu {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #232323;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #CD2C23;
    border-top: 5px solid #CD2C23;
    // position: absolute; // Remove this
    // right: 241px; // And this
}
```

Comment: I came with the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your inline css for cssmenu and add this your main css file.

```
 #cssmenu {
   height: 70px;
   background-color: rgb(35,35,35);
   border-bottom: 5px solid #cd2c23;
   border-top: 5px solid #cd2c23;
   width:940.5px;
   margin:auto;
   z-index: 1000;
 }
```